# PHP curl is not parsing POST data

Tags: php, post, curl, https, xampp

So i am trying to send a HTTPS POST request to a website but curl is not setting my post data nor my headers.
Here is my code(i changed the domain and values):

```
<?php

//Create connection
$ch = curl_init();

//Set the headers
$headers = array();
$headers[] = "Connection: Keep-Alive";
$headers[] = "Host: website.com";
$headers[] = "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
$headers[] = "Something: Something_Data";

//Set the POST data
$headers = array();
$headers[] = "Connection: Keep-Alive";
$headers[] = "Host: website.com";
$headers[] = "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
$headers[] = "Something: Something_Data";

// Configure the request (HTTPS)
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "https://website.com/test");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, "MyUserAgentHere");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1); //just to be sure...

//Set the POST data and Headers
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, urlencode("DATA1=VAL1&DATA2=VAL2")); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers); 

$result=curl_exec($ch);
echo $result;

curl_close($ch);
?>
```

So basically i'm trying to send a HTTPS POST request to https://website.com/test". The request is sent and i get an answer but for some reasons it doesn't parse the POST data nor the Headers.

Here is my request in fiddler:

```
POST https://website.com/test HTTP/1.1
Host: website.com
```

Here is the answer from the request:

```
HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request
Date: Fri, 06 Nov 2015 00:57:15 GMT
Server: Apache
Cache-Control: no-store
Pragma: no-cache
Connection: close
Content-Type: application/json;charset=UTF-8
Content-Length: 158

{"error":"unsupported DATA1"}
```

As you can see, the POST data and the headers are not set in my request for some reason. I have no idea why curl is not setting my headers and my post fields.

Infos: I am using XAMPP with php5.

Comment: Try taking `DATA1` out of your CURL request and see if you get the same response.

Comment: Do you have control over the server you are posting to? If so, can you issue a `print_r($_POST);`?

Comment: Why are you setting `$headers` twice?

Comment: DATA1 and DATA2 are actually required and have a real value that i need to send. If i were to remove them i would still get a bad request since their values are required

A normal request looks like this:

    POST https://website.com/test HTTP/1.1
    User-Agent: MuUserAgent
    Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
    Something: Something_Data
    Host: website.come
    Content-Length: 205
    
    DATA1=VAL1&DATA2=VAL2

And i would get this answer:
    HTTP/1.1 200 OK
    (excluding some... chars limit)


    {"result":"A result here"}

Comment: I don't have control of the server i am posting to sadly, but i use fiddler to check the packets and there is only 2 things in my headers. 

POST https://website.com/test
Host: website.com

the rest is empty

Comment: Do you have docs for http://website.com/test specifying the format in which they are expecting your POST data to be formatted?

Comment: @StackKev This "fiddler" you speak of is not something you're looking at in your web browser's developer tools, is it?

Comment: No, i'm using fiddler from telerik to monitor my requests.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You shouldn't URL-encode the entire parameter string, that will encode the `=` and `&` so they're no longer delimiters. You should just encode the values.

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, 'DATA1=' . urlencode($val1) . '&DATA2' . urlencode($val2));
```

You can use an array instead, and cURL will do the encoding for you.

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, array('DATA1' => $val1, 'DATA2' => $val2));
```

If you use the array mechanism, remove the `Content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded` header, because cURL sends it in `multipart/form-data` format.

Comment: I just changed it and sadly my request is still empty. I have no idea why my request is empty.

Note: i edited my code to the updated one.

Comment: Please put the question back. How can anyone understand the reason for my answer if they can't see the original code in your question?

Comment: Try taking out the `Content-type` header, that's not how cURL encodes the array.

Comment: I took it out and still no POST/HEAD data in my request.
i will also change back my original post so people will understand your answer!

Comment: Try getting rid of all your headers -- none of them seem necessary.

Comment: Well i need to send them, one of my headers is 'Something'  with its own value and i must send it in the header else i would get a bad request saying i need the 'Something' header.

Comment: OK, try just sending that header, don't replace the standard headers like `Host`.

Comment: Alright everything works ! I removed some of the headers like you said and i got the request and the response i was expecting! Thanks a lot Barmar!